# Javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

Method # 1

```
function transform(ar) {
    var alStr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {

        alStr[i] = (function(v) {
            return (function() {
                return v;
            });
        }(ar[i]));
    }

    return alStr;
}

var a = ["a", 24, { foo: "bar" }];
var b = transform(a);
a[1];
b[1]();
```

Method # 2

```
function transform(ar) {
    var alStr = [];
    for(var a in ar) {
        var O = function() {
            return a;
        }
        alStr.push(O);
    }
    return alStr; 
}

var a = ["a", 24, { foo: "bar" }];
var b = transform(a);
a[1];
b[1]();
```

The above mentioned methods are used to convert an array objects into individual functions which on execution return the specific array object. Want to know why method #1 works and method #2 doesnt.

Comment: **Only** new functions introduce new variables .. this question has come up a good bit on SO. Search for "javascript loop last value" or similar.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903130/373378) for a good explanation.

Comment: In your non-working code, put the `var a` *before* the `for` loop, and it'll do a better job of reflecting reality. There are no variables that are local to the `for` statement, because in JavaScript, scope is always defined by a `function`. This means *all* the functions being created in the `for` loop are referring to the same `a` variable, which is local to the `transform` function.

Comment: see [this article](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) for a reference on variable scoping and hoisting in javascript.

Comment: @32bitkid : Both your links were very helpful, thanks a lot.

Comment: Lots of answers, but no one has reminded you not to use for..in with an array unless you have a very good reason to do so (such as a sparse array), take precautions to avoid inherited properties (such as a *hasOwnProperty* test) and don't expect members to returned in any particular order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Method #2 there are two problems:

1. You are returning the key name, `a`, rather than the array value, `ar[a]`. That is, rather than `return a;` you want `return ar[a];`.
2. The function will always refer to the last value looped through because it references the same scope object. To create a new scope object you will need a closure, a `with` block, or a bound function.

With a closure:

```
for(var a in ar) { 
  var O = (function(val) { 
    return function() { 
      return val; 
     }
  })(ar[a]);
  alStr.push(O); 
}
```

With a `with` block:

```
for(var a in ar) { 
  with({val: ar[a]}) {
    alStr.push(function() { 
      return val; 
     });
  }
}
```

With a bound function:

```
for(var a in ar) { 
  var O = function(x) { return x; };
  alStr.push(O.bind(null, arr[a]));
}
```

Comment: Point #1 was a typo from my side, sorry. Still trying to understand the second point.

Comment: Even though this answer is correct, `function.bind` ought to be preferred here imo.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco Good point, I updated my answer and +1 to yours.

Comment: +1 for the `with` block trick.  That is a statement that I think about occasionally, but rarely (never) use.  I just may start using it a bit more.

Comment: The "with closure" example is actually *without* a closure. It's the closure in the OP's second example that is the issue, using an immediately invoked function expression breaks the closure.

Answer (score 3):

Peter Olson is correct. However, the more modern (correct?) way of doing this is by using `function.bind(obj, val)`. Introduced somewhat recently, `function.bind` allows you to pass variables by value and in certain contexts. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

So, you could write something like this:

```
function transform(ar) {
    var alStr = [];
    var O = function(x) { return x }
    for(var a in ar) {
        alStr.push(O.bind(null, ar[a]));
    }
    return alStr; 
}

var a = ["a", 24, 12345];
var b = transform(a);
console.log(a[2]);
b[2]();
```

This is a more correct paradigm due to the fact that initiating closures has very clear implications. Using bind, however, tends to be a functional approach to be used specifically when function calling (in particular contexts or with particular stipulations).

Using a with block also has some downsides (there are plenty of questions about it).

**Bonus**: If you wanted `b` to also represent subsequent changes to the `a` array, this solution solves that problem:

```
function transform(ar) {
    var alStr = [];
    var O = function(x) { return ar[x] }
    for(var a in ar) {
        alStr.push(O.bind(null, a));
    }
    return alStr; 
}

var a = ["a", 24, 12345];
var b = transform(a);
console.log(a[2]);
console.log(b[2]());
console.log("*********");
a[2] = "new value!";
console.log(a[2]);
console.log(b[2]());
```