# Javascript closures for iterated function definitions

Tags: javascript, function, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821484/javascript-closure)

This has probably been asked before, but...

If I want a list of functions

```
var funs = [
  function(){ console.log(1); },
  function(){ console.log(2); },
  function(){ console.log(3); },
  function(){ console.log(4); },
  function(){ console.log(5); } ]
```

it would seem that one could make it by something like:

```
var funs = [];
for(var i=1; i <= 5; i++){
  funs.push(function(){ console.log(i) };
}
```

Which doesn't work, as the variable `i` is a single variable bound to all the functions, so that

```
funs[0](); funs[1](); funs[2](); funs[3](); funs[4]();
```

outputs

```
6
6
6
6
6
```

not

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

This isn't the output I want. I guess I need to force javascript to bind a copy of the value of `i` at the time the function is created, instead of closing with the reference for `i`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is passing the function through the argument of a self-executing function:

```
for(...) {
    (function(i) {
        // here you have a new i in every loop
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Using closures works, but I just want to add that the modern way (JS >1.8.5) of doing this is by using `bind` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: You mean `push( console.log.bind(console, i) )`? Sure, that's more elegant than nesting two functions.

Comment: You can actually do `push( console.log.bind(null, i) )` also (since you don't really care what `this` is for our purposes), but yeah.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: That will break at least in Chrome since `console` *must* be the context of `log()`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: You're right! I was testing on Firebug. Different strokes, as they say.