# Javascript - use variable in a function, within a function

Tags: javascript, variables

this code was bothering me the whole day. Lets say ledCount = 9, the code gets the elements by ID without any problem, but since it would have to bind a seperate function onClick, and since the variable i is local, the writeLED function always gets the first parameter 10 (which is max i+1), but it would need to get the current i+1, like the getElementBy id i+1 does. Anyone can solve the puzzle?

```
function showLED(ledCount){
for(var i = 0;i<=(ledCount-1);i++){
    if(color[i] == 0){
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+(i+1)).onclick = function(){writeLED((i+1),1); } ;
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+(i+1)).value="light is on";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+(i+1)).onclick = function(){writeLED((i+1),0); } ;
        document.getElementById('buttonLED'+(i+1)).value="light is off";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to wrap it in a self-executing function to create a new scope where you can preserve the current value of the incrementing function.

You can do that inline like this:

```
document.getElementById('buttonLED'+(i+1)).onclick = function(loopincrement){   
    return function(){writeLED((loopincrement+1),1); } ;

}(i)
```

or as a pulled out function like this:

```
function writeLEDInNewScope(inc){
    return function(){ writeLED(inc,1)};
}

document.getElementById('buttonLED'+(i+1)).onclick = writeLEDinNewScope(i+1);
```

The outer function will preserve the i value's current value for the inner onclick function.  It executes immediately and returns the inner function that you want bound to the onclick property.  It will maintain the reference to the `loopincrement` variable, which won't be effected by future loop iterations.

Comment: Even though this is correct, the more modern way of doing it is with `func.apply()` -- either way, OP should read up about closures.

Comment: You can just shadow `i` by passing it as an argument to the outer function.

Comment: @David - I though that apply will actually execute the function with an explicit `this` and array of arguments, are you sure it is O.K to assign it to callback?

Comment: @bfavaretto wrote it too quickly.  Fixed now

Comment: I'm picky (again): While the self executing function is a closure (every function in JS is (kind of)), this is not the reason why this solution works. The event handler the OP assigns is a closure as well (in fact, the way closures are implemented in JS is the source of the problem). What the self executing function does is creating a new scope. It would work as well if it wasn't a closure. Even more so, if you consider a closure to be a function with free variables, then your "wrapper" function is not a closure since there are no free variables.

Comment: @pure_code: I meant to say `bind`, oops. I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821484/javascript-closure/11821603#11821603

Comment: just earlier today I was thinking I should update this pattern in my code base to bind.

Comment: `your_function.bind(some_this,arg1,arg2....)` should do it.

Comment: @FelixKling nothing wrong with being picky.  I appreciate having it pointed out when my language is not as precise as it could be

Comment: @pure_code: from what I understand, `bind` has a slight performance hit, but I think it's going to be optimized soon(tm) in most mainstream browsers. It just looks/reads better than having all these weird dangling closures.

Comment: well...yea...that's what I meant.

Comment: @David: It works as long as you don't need access to `this` (e.g. the element the handler is bound to).

Comment: this question has been asked 100+ times on SO I'm sure.

Comment: and yes, this question is asked like 3 times a day :P should probably be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [infamous for loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem). You have to rewrite your code like this:

```
function callback(x) {
    return function() { writeLED(x, 1); };
}

function showLED(ledCount) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= (ledCount - 1); i++)(function(i) {
        if (color[i] == 0) {
            document.getElementById('buttonLED' + (i + 1)).onclick = callback(i + 1);
            document.getElementById('buttonLED' + (i + 1)).value = "light is on";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('buttonLED' + (i + 1)).onclick = callback(i + 1);
            document.getElementById('buttonLED' + (i + 1)).value = "light is off";
        }
    })(i);
}
```